# how to reconfigure network on Ubuntu Server LTS 16.04 without reboot

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ubuntu-16.04

I ask a very simple question, how to reconfigure network on Ubuntu Server LTS 16.04 without reboot ?

Usaly, I edit "/etc/network/interfaces" make the changes and then run "sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart" and everything done. It works on all Linux Debian family I know, but it has no effect on all Ubuntu Server LTS 16.04 I have installed.

I always need to reboot the host to update my network configuration (this take me back to the 90s when needed to restart Windows when changing TCP/IP setting)

I also ran :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
```

I can confirm that all Interfaces are down with :

```
sudo ifconfig
```

Start again but, still loading old config.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking start
```

And also tried :

```
sudo ifdown eno1
sudo ifconfig
sudo ifup eno1
```

Comment: Did you try flushing the IP addresses via `flush` and restarting via `systemctl`? `sudo ip addr flush eno1 && sudo systemctl restart networking.service`?

Comment: It works when doing : `sudo ifdown eno1 &&
sudo ip addr flush eno1
&& sudo ifup eno1` thank you

Comment: I tried `systemctl restart networking.service` I have the same issue.  So networking.service look not flushing interfaces.

Comment: I'd recommend (as always) to check syslog and your config itself, maybe even add it to your question.

Comment: You should close your question, as it is resolved